# Уточняющий комментарий — провал аудита?

Tags: обсуждение, аудит

Попался мне вопрос, который уже видел, но он был без ответа. Соответственно я решил, что человек по-новой задал точно такой же вопрос. Чтобы это проверить, я решил написать комментарий с вопросом, после которого я <strike>уныло вздохнул</strike> понял всю ситуацию.

Почему же комментарий обязательно считается критикой проверяемого сообщения? Те же рекомендации по написанию вопросов можно давать и хорошим сообщениям. Вероятно, правки тоже считаются провалом аудита со скрытым положительным вопросом, хотя в нём может оказаться что-то для исправления?

Comment: Да с аудитами вообще [беда какая-то](http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/16/0501/h_1462111357_8893969_adb734094d.png).

Comment: @D-side Для аудитов считается допустимым быть бредовыми, потому что они генерируются машиной. Проваливать бредовые аудиты — это нормально. Вот если система забанит, тогда уже можно жаловаться и пинать модераторов, чтобы разбанили. Они проверят, и если проверки в пределах нормы, то разбанят.